# Fast packet processing from stream

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, networkstream, packets

First background. I have a camera that my app is connected to via Ethernet cable and it performs operations based on commands I send and responds with commands back.

If I take the camera trigger command as an example. 
The camera will take a picture if I send it 'T1'. All commands use a start and end char to mark the start and end of pack so the full packet I send will look like this

(char)0x02T1(char)0x03

with (char)0x02 as the start of packet and (char)0x03 as the end of pack.

The camera will then take a picture and send the same command back to say it is done. You can also set the camera to send some data back when it has taken the picture. In my case I have the camera inspecting a few areas and I want some values from the inspection.

So the return of the camera would be something like 'T1' and then say '1,1,500,20,300'

On to the problem. I am using a `TcpClient` and a `NetworkStream` for the communication but I am struggling with processing the packets on the receiving side. I have tried various methods but they seem slow or don't guarantee I get all the data.

Firstly I need something that will read all the data and make sure I have all the data.

Secondly I need something that can process the data and split up into packets and do this as fast as possible.

This is just one method I have tried and full credit goes to the person who made the `StreamReaderExtensions`. I'm sure I found it on here somewhere.

```
internal static class StreamReaderExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadUntil(this StreamReader reader, string delimiter)
    {
        List<char> buffer = new List<char>();
        CircularBuffer<char> delim_buffer = new CircularBuffer<char>(delimiter.Length);

        while (reader.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            char c = (char)reader.Read();
            delim_buffer.Enqueue(c);
            if (delim_buffer.ToString() == delimiter)
            {
                if (buffer.Count > 0)
                {
                    yield return new String(buffer.ToArray());
                    buffer.Clear();
                }
                continue;
            }
            buffer.Add(c);
        }
    }

    private class CircularBuffer<T> : Queue<T>
    {
        private int _capacity;

        public CircularBuffer(int capacity)
            : base(capacity)
        {
            _capacity = capacity;
        }

        new public void Enqueue(T item)
        {
            if (base.Count == _capacity)
            {
                base.Dequeue();
            }
            base.Enqueue(item);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            List<String> items = new List<string>();
            foreach (var x in this)
            {
                items.Add(x.ToString());
            };
            return String.Join("", items);
        }
    }
}
```

and my process method. `_stream` is `TcpClient.GetStream()`

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const char StartOfPacket = (char)0x02;
    public const char EndOfPacket = (char)0x03;
}

private IEnumerable<string> ProcessResponse()
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(_stream);
    var packets = streamReader.ReadUntil(new string(new char[] {Constants.EndOfPacket}));
    return packets;
}
```

Comment: You should read per char. Just read a big block and check the received size. Parse the block until you find the delimiter and remove the parsed block. Repeat until you have half packets.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen half packets?

Comment: a message could be split up in more receives/packets. This is because it is a stream instead of a datagram. If you receive only 1 char at the time, it is always splitup in multiple receives,

Comment: ah I think I understand, I have a few things to look into for the processing. What about ensuring I have all the data?

Answer (score 0):

I made some pseudo code for, I didn't tested it, but it might give you a direction. *This can't be static*

```
char[] _buffer = new char[4 * 1024 * 1024];
int currentPosition;

public bool ReadNext(StreamReader reader, char delimiter, out string value)
{
    // read as many chars from the stream.
    int charsRead = reader.ReadBlock(_buffer, currentPosition, _buffer.Length - currentPosition);

    // keep track of the current position.
    currentPosition += charsRead;

    // find the first delimiter.
    for (int i = 0; i < currentPosition; i++)
    {
        if (_buffer[i] == delimiter)
        {
            // a complete packet was found, copy it to a string.
            value = new string(_buffer, 0, i);
            // move the rest of the data back to the start of the buffer.
            Array.Copy(_buffer, i, _buffer, 0, _buffer.Length - i);
            // decrease the current position also.
            currentPosition -= i;
            // return true because you have data.
            return true;
        }
    }

    // no complete packet was found.
    value = String.Empty;
    return false;
}
```

---

Usage:

```
string data;

while(true)
{
    if(ReadNext(reader, (char)0x03, out data))
        MessageBox.Show(data);
}
```

Like I said **untested**, this is just a brainfart... You might need to add the check of the start of packet.

Comment: Thanks for that. I will give it a good look over and try it out.

Comment: Just got round to trying this out and for some reason I get a "System.IO.Exception" when executing the `ReadBlock`.
Inner exception says "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period time....."
Writing to the same stream works fine.

Comment: Does the connection is blocked by a firewall? (other side)

Comment: No its not blocked. I seem to have it working now but I had to switch to using `reader.Read`rather than `reader.ReadBlock`